# How do I use a named export from an external script in Angular?

Tags: angular, interface, cdn, declare, dexie

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4666q1?file=src%2Fdb%2Fdb.ts is a great demo of using Dexie in Angular, but instead of npm installing and importing, I would like to dynamically load Dexie **AND Table** from a CDN as described here: https://www.ngdevelop.tech/loading-external-libraries-from-cdn-in-angular-application/

After loading dynamically, my goal is to replace the following (db.ts line 1):

```
   import Dexie, { Table } from 'dexie';
```

with something like this:

```
   declare let Dexie: any;
```

which works great for default export "Dexie", but not sure how to declare and use the named export interface "Table" which is needed for lines 20 and 21:

```
  todoItems!: Table<TodoItem, number>;
  todoLists!: Table<TodoList, number>;
```

[image: Table in db.ts]I've tried

```
   declare let Table: any;
```

```
  todoItems!: Dexie.Table<TodoItem, number>;
```

neither works.  What should I do?

Comment: I guess theoretically you shouldn’t have to..? To use, I would expect Dexie.Table to work maybe?

Comment: Typings are included with the npm lib but I doubt they are there for the production ready CDN lib.  No types are being used in the example of loading from the cdn that you linked to.